# Probability of any player in a 4 player game being in the same seat across 4 games

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The setting is you have 4 games, each with the same 4 players. In each game the seating arrangement is uniformly random, i.e. the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th seats are randomly decided each game. I'm interested in finding the probability that any of those 4 players happens to be in the same seat in all 4 games. Here is my potential solution, which doesn't look completely sound to me.

1, 2, 3, and 4 are the events where the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th seats have the same players in each of the games.

$$\begin{align*}
P(1 \cup 2 \cup 3 \cup 4) &= P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) \\\\
&- P(1 \cap 2) - P(1 \cap 3) - \dots - P(3 \cap 4) \\\\
&+ P(1 \cap 2 \cap 3) + \dots + P(2 \cap 3 \cap 4) \\\\
&- P(1 \cap 2 \cap 3 \cap 4) \\\\
&= 4(\frac{1}{4})^3 - 6(\frac{1}{12})^3 + 4(\frac{1}{24})^3 - (\frac{1}{24})^3 \\\\
&= \frac{819}{13824} \approx 5.92\%
\end{align*}$$

I'm getting probability of a single seat having the same player in each game as $(\frac{1}{4})^3$ since you need the 3 remaining games to match the player in that seat in the first game. Probability of two seats having the same players is $(\frac{1}{12})^3$ since you have a 1/4 for the first seat to match and a 1/3 for the other seat to match, again 3 times. Where I'm most concerned is that intersection of three events and intersection of four events seem to be the same thing because once you have 3 seats maintaining a player, the 4th seat must then also maintain the same player. Does this mess up the inclusion exclusion principle?

Comment: The fact that having three people in their own seats forces all four people to be in their own seats does not interfere with the application of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: When you write "any player being in the same seat...", do you mean *exactly* one player or *at least* one player or *all* players, please clarify

Comment: Your method seems right.

Comment: @trueblueanil I meant at least one player.

Comment: OK, so your PIE is correct ! "Any" cast a doubt in my mind. Cheers ! $\;\;$:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See **Added** portion for a different interpretation of the question

You don't need to use inclusion-exclusion at all here.

In the first round, they can be seated any which way.
Each of the succeedding $3$ rounds has $4!=24$ equiprobable permutations of which only one satisfies the required condition

Thus $Pr = \dfrac1{4!^3} = \dfrac 1 {13824}$

---

### *Added*

N. F. Taussig has interpreted that what you are asking is that at least one player occupies her seat in all four games, and seeing your working using inclusion-exclusion, that seems to be your intent although you haven't yet responded to my query.

With the interpretation of N.F. Taussig, your application of inclusion-exclusion is okay.

Comment: We want the probability that at least one player sits in the same seat in all four games.   You seem to be answering a different question, namely that all the players remain in the same seat through all four games.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: OK, I'll amend it

Comment: Yeah I did mean at least one player. Seems good then thanks